# python list of sets find symmetric difference in all elements

Tags: python, set, reduce

Consider this list of sets

```
my_input_list= [
{1,2,3,4,5},
{2,3,7,4,5},
set(),
{1,2,3,4,5,6},
set(),]
```

I want to get the only exclusive elements 6 and 7 as the response, list or set.  Set preferred.

I tried 
`print reduce(set.symmetric_difference,my_input_list)` but that gives

```
{2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

And i tried sorting the list by length, smallest first raises an error due to two empty sets. Largest first gives the same result as unsorted.

Any help or ideas please?
Thanks :)

Comment: what makes `6 and 7` exclusive? can you elaborate?

Comment: You mean you only want the elements that are only in 1 set?

Comment: I want the elements that only appear once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the most straightforward solution is to count everything and return the elements that only appear once.

This solution uses `chain.from_iterable` (to flatten your sets) + `Counter` (to count things). Finally, use a set comprehension to filter elements with count == 1.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(my_input_list))
print({k for k in c if c[k] == 1})
{6, 7}
```

A quick note; the empty literal `{}` is used to indicate an empty *`dict`*, not *`set`*. For the latter, use `set()`.

Comment: That note explains why I was receiving a warning about sorted list.  It was erroring on being passed a dict.

Comment: @Joylove hah, I thought that was the case... made sure to add it in as the garnish atop the meat 'n potatoes ;-)

Comment: (sorry bout the comment above, been following Food Wars a bit too closely of late)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.chain` and `collection.Counter`:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

r = {k for k,v in Counter(chain.from_iterable(my_input_list)).items() if v==1}
```

Comment: This is in my answer, however I'd suggest using `chain.from_iterable` instead of `chain(*...)` since the former is more efficient.

Comment: I wrote this answer before I saw yours.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't dispute that. Although this _was_ posted 4 minutes later ;-) Another minor point, I'd recommend adding the import statements at the top, for clarity.